# jquery revert overlay div

Tags: jquery

I have a div that shows an image:

```
<div id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;background-image:url(../../../images/video.JPG)"></div>
```

I overlay a video player (flowplayer) on top of that div when someone clicks a button:

```
flowplayer("player", "mysite/js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.swf", {
        clip: {
            url: theUrl,
            provider: 'rtmp'
        },
        plugins: {
            rtmp: {
                url: "js/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.10.swf",
                netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://myhost.com/recordings'
            }
        }
    });
```

I've got logic that when someone deletes that video I want the player to go away and be left with the div with the image only.

So I can't just use:

```
jQuery("#player").hide();
```

That hides the player and the original div with the image. How can I hide the player but not the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply empty the div...

```
jQuery("#player").empty();
```

I'm not familiar with flowplayer but that will remove all child elements, which I would assume would simply be a swf player object.

You could alternatively hide all child objects, but that would leave the video still playing...

```
jQuery("#player *").hide();
```

Comment: Ah, knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!